# How to use component props from MDX with Codehike Bright in NextJS

Tags: next.js, syntax-highlighting, mdxjs, react-server-components

I am using Codehike Bright with NextJS 13.2 and the app directory (using React Server Components).

I am also using MDX.

This is the TSX file that loads the MDX content and passes a version prop - `page.tsx`:

```js
import Content from './content.mdx'

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <section>
            <Content version="1.2.3" />
        </section>
    )
}
```

This is the MDX file that includes the code fragment and references the version prop - `content.mdx`:

````markdown
# Some Page

The latest version is {props.version}.

```xml
<!-- title pom.xml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>some.artefact.id</artifactId>
    <version>{props.version}</version>
</dependency>
```
````

This is the rendered output:

[image: Rendered page with expected version in the plain-text, but not in the code fragment]

This displays the prop value in the plain-text part as expected.

But how do you get the prop value to display within the codeblock?

Answer (score 0):

As stated here: https://github.com/code-hike/codehike/discussions/270#discussioncomment-3407414, it is not possible in Code Hike currently, and I assume this is also true for Bright.

However they propose some solutions with `useEffect` or CSS pseudo selectors.

You can adapt the CSS solution to React components in NextJS by using Styled JSX like so:

**content.mdx**

````
# Some Page

The latest version is {props.version}.

```js
# title pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>some.artefact.id</artifactId>
    # withClass[13] some-class
    <version></version>
</dependency>
```
````

**page.tsx**

```js
import Content from './content.mdx'

export default function Page() {
    const version = "1.2.3";

    return (
        <section className="with-global-styles">
            <Content version={version} />
        </section>
        <style jsx global>{`
          .with-global-styles .some-class::after {
            content: "${version}";
          }
        `}</style>
    )
}
```

Notice how I changed the code block language to ```` ```js ```` because [not all languages support comments](https://codehike.org/docs/annotations#comment-syntax). You might want to choose one that better highlights your code.